# Set Reminders Automatically in Google Calendar

Tags: email, google-calendar, reminder

My dad is now extensively using Google Calendar for tracking his investments, changing of password(s) etc.,

He wants to create events with the minimum number of clicks. And, so this is his approach.

Launch Google Calendar
Choose the Date
Click on the Time
In the pop up, type the event description

Now, he wants to have the Email reminder automatically setup. Currently, he is now forced to go into the Event and then set the email reminder.

Is there any global setting in Google Calendar where he can specify that the email reminder is always set for all the events he creates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the left side under the title my calendars there is a link that says configuration, click that one first. Then you enter a page with several tabs, but by default you enter in your desired tab which is calendar. In this tabs you will find a link called notifications, click that link. In that page you can set all the reminders of the events that you want for before the date of the apointment, and you can program as many reminders as you want, in your own desired times.

Then you wont have to configure each appointment reminders, there will all work with your default configuration.